# android how to insert value in database

Tags: android, database

i have database which work fine.i use edittext to insert data in to database.data inserting is fine working.but with out edittext how can i store value to my database through code.anyone like to help me.
thanks in advance.

this is my dbhelper class.

```
public class FoodDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PKFM.DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
        "CREATE TABLE "+ Food.NewDishInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_QUANTITY+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CALORIE+" INTEGER,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_FAT+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_PROTEIN+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_SUGAR+" TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CARBOHYDRATES+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
public FoodDbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","Database created / opened...");
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","Table created...");


}
public void addInformations(String name ,String quantity, Integer calorie, String fat ,
                            String protein,String sugar,String carbohydrates, SQLiteDatabase db){


    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_QUANTITY,quantity);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CALORIE,calorie);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_FAT,fat);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_PROTEIN,protein);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_SUGAR,sugar);
    contentValues.put(Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CARBOHYDRATES,carbohydrates);

    db.insert(Food.NewDishInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);


    Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION","one row inserted...");
}
```

i do some thing like this but not data inserted

```
foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(context);
    foodDbHelper.addInformations("Paratha", "1 piece", 260,"8.99 g","5.16 g","2.18 g","38.94 g",sqLiteDatabase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for...
How else would you like to obtain the information to store into your database?

This seems more like a user experience question instead of a 'how to'.
The correct method seems to already be included in your code to push whatever string you want, however you want.

Comment: What is the difference between what you have there versus what you do with an edittext field?

Comment: i also insert data with edittext. but i want to store value in my project.

Comment: i want whenever i run this app on any device it give me the values which i stored